# jquery make alert equal to an array of names

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code above looks to see if my check boxes are checked or unchecked. IF they are unchecked then it logs in the console the names of the checkboxes that are unchecked. I want to take those names and put them in the alert box and am struggling to access the element.name outside the each loop. Anyone have any ideas?

```js
// when page is ready
jQuery("#user_price_accept").submit(function(event) {
  // on form submit
  event.preventDefault();
  var test = jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
  var test2 = '';
  test.each((i, element) => {
    console.log(element.name)
    test2 = element.name;
  })
  return test2;
  if (test.length > 0) {
    alert(test2);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's with `return test2`? Nothing after that will execute

Comment: trying to get the variable accessible outside of the  each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a handy [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method which you can use to transform a collection of elements into an array of data.

You could then [*join*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that array into a string and `alert` it

```js
jQuery("#user_price_accept").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const test = jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
  const names = test.map((_, el) => el.name).get() // get() returns the underlying array
  if (names.length) {
    alert(names.join(", "))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. In the above, for the cons test, am I adding that to the function or inside the .each or am I replacing the existing var test?

Comment: @Manny I've update my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

First, you're returning before the alert. That will stop execution of anything in the same bracket that occurs after that.

Second, you're reassigning test2 inside of your loop. Even if you can access it outside of the loop, all you're going to get is the name of the last element. Try using `test2 += ', ' + element.name`

Third, this bit here:

```
if (test.length > 0) {
    alert(test2);
  }
```

looks like you are checking the length of an unchanged list. Except the test you defined above is another jQuery object (which I'm not sure has a length built-in, but I digress). Still unchanged though. If this is what you are looking for, that's fine, but I would put the `test.each((...` inside of the if statment

Answer (score 0):

You are missing concatenation of name and every time test2 gets replaced with a new name. Also returning test2 in function will go outside of function and alert code will not be executed. I have modified few lines

**test2 += element.name; // names are added in test 2**

**return test2; // remove this line or handle after alert code**

```
// when page is ready
jQuery("#user_price_accept").submit(function(event) {
  // on form submit
  event.preventDefault();
  var test = jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
  var test2 = '';
  test.each((i, element) => {
    console.log(element.name)
    test2 += "," + element.name;
  })
  //return test2;
  if (test.length > 0) {
    alert(test2);
  }
});
```

Comment: Might be a little difficult to read the names without any delimiters

Comment: @Phil modified with comma separation in code. Thanks for the comments